# Accessing an array element whos key is an element from another array

Tags: php, arrays

How does one do this?

Here's an example;
Say I have an array called $Foo.

```
$Foo = array("cool" => "Manchu", "Mama" => "loofoo", "Lizard" => "Foof on you");
```

...and then there's this other array...

```
$OtherArray = array("cool", "Mama", "Lizard");
```

How can I print `$Foo[$OtherArray[1]];`

I don't really want to:

```
$ThisThing = $OtherArray[1];
print "$Foo[$ThisThing]";
```

Comment: The only problem with `print "$Foo[$OtherArray[1]]";` is the quotes, so if you need it in a longer string, concatenate the value rather than substitute it.

Comment: Well, how DO you want to do it?  What info do you know?

Comment: The problem that I was having is that when I tried to access the array element in this way, it was breaking the page.

print "$Foo[$OtherArray[1]]";  // Doesn't work

$ThisThing = $OtherArray[1];
print "$Foo[$ThisThing]";  // Does work, but feels sloppy.

I did figure out, once I saw Madhur's answer, that I can do this;

echo $Foo[$OtherArray[1]];

Answer (score 0):

You can try (explanation in code comments):

```
// First value of $OtherArray is cool
// We can access it using $OtherArray[0]. It is also a key in the $Foo array
// This would print the value corresponding to 'cool' key in the $Foo array
echo $Foo[$OtherArray[0]];

// Displays Manchu
```